# Power Query: How do I get an EndingDate on a row when I only have a StartingDate?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need some help in Power Query with getting an EndingDate on a row. Can anyone help me out? The EndingDate will be the date prior to the new StartingDate.

| No | Sup | StartingDate | Costs | Expected result (EndingDate) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30000 | 01-1-2023 | 100 | 13-1-2022 |
| 1 | 30000 | 14-1-2023 | 105 | 27-1-2022 |
| 1 | 30000 | 28-1-2023 | 110 |  |
| 2 | 30000 | 01-1-2023 | 110 | 17-1-2023 |
| 2 | 30000 | 18-1-2023 | 116 | 29-1-2023 |
| 2 | 30000 | 30-1-2023 | 120 |  |
| 3 | 30000 | 01-1-2023 | 90 | 5-1-2023 |
| 3 | 30000 | 06-1-2023 | 100 | 8-1-2023 |
| 3 | 30000 | 09-1-2023 | 105 |  |

Comment: Please paste your sample data as copiable text and mark your old questions as solved. Thanks

Comment: @DavidBacci I pasted it as copiable text and marked my old questions as solved.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show your expected results too so it is clear what the requirement is.

Comment: @DavidBacci Added a column with expected result, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"StartingDate", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"No"}, {{"data", each let
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(_, "PriorDate2", each Date.AddDays([StartingDate],-1)),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "PriorDate", each try #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[PriorDate2] otherwise null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"PriorDate2", "Index"})
    in #"Removed Columns"
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Sup ", "StartingDate", "Costs ", "PriorDate"}, {"Sup ", "StartingDate", "Costs ", "PriorDate"})
in   #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Slower solution: Add an index, and then add a custom column with formula:

```
= (x)=>try Date.AddDays(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [No]=x[No] and [Index]=x[Index]+1 )[StartingDate]{0},-1) otherwise null
```

like in this code

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index","PriorDate",(x)=>try Date.AddDays(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [No]=x[No] and [Index]=x[Index]+1 )[StartingDate]{0},-1) otherwise null),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"StartingDate", type date}, {"PriorDate", type date}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I fail to understand how to use this in Powerquery, can you explain how to implement the "Grouped Rows" step?

Comment: You can paste this code as shown into home..advanced editor....    Its written custom, you can't implement it from the graphical user interface

Comment: Thanks a million, it works brilliantly! Solution verified.

Comment: Added a non-grouping, slower, solution if you want it